# How to Solve Deserialization error ask sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, objectmapper

I'm attempting to convert the JSON output from my session and map it to a class that I've created using JAVA's ObjectMapper. When I run my tests on Lambda I get a Deserialisation error:

```
Deserialization error: com.amazon.ask.exception.AskSdkException
com.amazon.ask.exception.AskSdkException: Deserialization error
    at com.amazon.ask.util.impl.JacksonJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(JacksonJsonUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.amazon.ask.impl.AbstractSkill.execute(AbstractSkill.java:44)
    at com.amazon.ask.AlexaSkill.execute(AlexaSkill.java:22)
    at com.amazon.ask.SkillStreamHandler.handleRequest(SkillStreamHandler.java:71)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'AnswerIntent' as a subtype of [simple type, class com.amazon.ask.model.Request]: known type ids = [Alexa.Presentation.APL.UserEvent, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ItemsCreated, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ItemsDeleted, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ItemsUpdated, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ListCreated, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ListDeleted, AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ListUpdated, AlexaSkillEvent.SkillAccountLinked, AlexaSkillEvent.SkillDisabled, AlexaSkillEvent.SkillEnabled, AlexaSkillEvent.SkillPermissionAccepted, AlexaSkillEvent.SkillPermissionChanged, AudioPlayer.PlaybackFailed, AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished, AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished, AudioPlayer.PlaybackStarted, AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped, Connections.Request, Connections.Response, Display.ElementSelected, GameEngine.InputHandlerEvent, IntentRequest, LaunchRequest, Messaging.MessageReceived, PlaybackController.NextCommandIssued, PlaybackController.PauseCommandIssued, PlaybackController.PlayCommandIssued, PlaybackController.PreviousCommandIssued, SessionEndedRequest, System.ExceptionEncountered] (for POJO property 'request')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.amazon.ask.model.RequestEnvelope$Builder["request"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1628)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleUnknownTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:291)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:162)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:254)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:193)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3972)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2746)
    at com.amazon.ask.util.impl.JacksonJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(JacksonJsonUnmarshaller.java:48)
    ... 3 more
```

I did checks to ensure that my "riddleItem" variable is not null. The JSON values are being mapped to the Person class which just returns properties of a person. The code is shown below and I've highlighted the line which the error occurs on:

```
public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {

        Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = input.getAttributesManager().getSessionAttributes();
        System.out.println("This a FIRST debug");
        LOG.debug("This a FIRST debug");

        boolean correctAnswer;
        String speechText = null, response;
        System.out.println("This a SECOND debug");


        Map<String, String> riddleItem = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>)sessionAttributes.get(Attributes.RIDDLE_ITEM_KEY);
        Person person;

//        System.out.println("riddleItem " + riddleItem);
        if(riddleItem != null)
        {
            person = MAPPER.convertValue(riddleItem, Person.class); // ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
        }
        System.out.println("This a THIRD debug");

        PersonProperty personProperty = PersonProperty.valueOf((String) sessionAttributes.get(Attributes.RIDDLE_PROPERTY_KEY));
        int counter = (int) sessionAttributes.get(Attributes.COUNTER_KEY);
        int riddleGameScore = (int) sessionAttributes.get(Attributes.RIDDLE_SCORE_KEY);
        System.out.println("This a FOURTH debug");

        IntentRequest intentRequest = (IntentRequest) input.getRequestEnvelope().getRequest();
        correctAnswer = compareSlots(intentRequest.getIntent().getSlots(), getPropertyOfPerson(personProperty, person));
        System.out.println("This a FIFTH debug " + correctAnswer);

        if(correctAnswer)
        {
            riddleGameScore++;
            response = getSpeechExpressionCon(true);
            System.out.println("This a SIXTH debug " + response);

            sessionAttributes.put(Attributes.RIDDLE_SCORE_KEY, riddleGameScore);
        }
        else
        {
            response = getSpeechExpressionCon(false);
            System.out.println("This a SEVENTH debug " + response);

        }

        AnswerIntentHandler setup = new AnswerIntentHandler();
//
        if(riddle.getAnswer() != null)
        {
            speechText = "Hello " + riddle.getAnswer();
        }

        return input.getResponseBuilder()
                .withSimpleCard("RiddleSession", speechText)
                .withSpeech(speechText)
                .withShouldEndSession(true)
                .build();
}
```

[[Json Output of properties under "riddleItem" during Session][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jR60.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jR60.png)

I know my the values being mapped aren't empty thus I'm at a complete loss of ideas as to what's going on as I've come up short with possible ideas as to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as I came to realise that when mapping from JSON to a class, methods ('set' methods) for assigning the JSON values to the variables in the class must be created. A sample structure for example:

```
public class State {
    public State() {}

        public State(String name, String abbreviation, String capital, String statehoodYear, String statehoodOrder) {
            this.name = name;
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
            this.capital = capital;
            this.statehoodYear = statehoodYear;
            this.statehoodOrder = statehoodOrder;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getAbbreviation() {
            return abbreviation;
        }

        public String getCapital() {
            return capital;
        }

        public String getStatehoodYear() { return statehoodYear; }

        public String getStatehoodOrder() {
            return statehoodOrder;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }

        public void setCapital(String capital) {
            this.capital = capital;
        }

        public void setStatehoodYear(String statehoodYear) {
            this.statehoodYear = statehoodYear;
        }

        public void setStatehoodOrder(String statehoodOrder) {
            this.statehoodOrder = statehoodOrder;
        }
}
```

The declaration of an empty constructor is necessary when making use of multiple constructors where, one is parametric. In some cases without the inclusion of such constructor an error may be thrown so, to avoid the possibility of said error, adding the constructor as a "Dummy" so to say, is essential.